# Linux Prompt Change Content Within File based on File Name

Tags: linux, perl, replace

I know how to do a search and replace amongst group of files:

perl -pi -w -e 's/search/replace/g;' *.php

So I can use that to search for a keyword or phrase and change it.  But I have a more complicated task I dont know how to do.

I want to do a search and replace among all my php files to search for a specific Keyword and replace it with the File Name minus the extension.

Example:  Search the file Mountains.php for the keyword Trees and everywhere you see Trees, replace it with Mountains

Of course I want to be able to do that in batch, for a few hundred php files all with different names, however, all containing the search term Trees.

If someone is looking for an extra challenge, haha, it would be even better if I could do a more complex scenario such as....

Example: Search the file MountainTowns.php for the keyword Trees and everywhere you see Trees, replace it with "Mountain Towns"  (note the extra space, Capital Letters could would indicate where spaces go)

Thanks for your time and considering my question.

Comment: I like to use `-i~` when doing massive changes like that. Then you can do a `diff -u` to make sure your changes are correct, and you can easily delete the backups using `find -name '*~' -delete`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the filename is in $ARGV, so there is not much more work needed.

```
perl -i -pe '($x=$ARGV)=~s{.php$}{};s{Trees}{$x}g' BlueMountains.php RedMountains.php
```

Add in

```
$x=~s{(.)([A-Z])}{$1 $2}g;
```

to add the space before upcased letters, for a complete line of

```
perl -i -pe '($x=$ARGV)=~s{.php$}{};$x=~s{(.)([A-Z])}{$1 $2}g;s{Trees}{$x}g' BlueRedMountains.php
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, a real help! With a little more thought I am very confident I can complete my task and shave hours off my project.

Comment: `[A-Z]` should probably be replaced by `[[:upper:]]`, to be somewhat more internationalized.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
printf "%s\n" *.php |perl -pwe 's|(.*).php|perl -pi -we "s/Trees/$1/g;" $&|' | bash
```

This uses perl to write a script to do you bidding.

Other little languages could be employed, like awk or:

```
 printf "%s\n" *.php |sed 'h;s/\.php//;s/\B[A-Z]/ &/;G;s|\(.*\)\n\(.*\)|sed -i "s/Trees/\1/g" \2|' | bash
```

This uses sed to provide a solution for the second request.

Answer (score -1):

You want a separate replacement for each file, so run a separate search and replace for each:

```
for file in *.php; do sed -i "s/foo/${file%.*}/g" "$file"; done
```

And your second request is a bit harder, it at least requires a subshell.

```
for file in *; do sed -i "s/bar/$(echo ${file%.*} | sed 's/\(.\)\([A-Z]\)/\1 \2/')/g" "$file"; done
```

It's a bit more readable if you put it in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
for file in "$@"; do
        replacement=$(echo ${file%.*} | sed 's/\(.\)\([A-Z]\)/\1 \2/')
        sed -i "s/bar/$replacement/g" "$file"; 
done
```

This will work over all the arguments passed it, so call with `./script.sh *.php`.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote? Did I make a mistake somewhere? Misunderstand the question? Not unnecessarily invoke perl?